# tkinter asksaveas not saving data

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter

Hi all and Merry Christmas!

I have a text entry widget and a save as button to save the contents of the text box to a .txt file. But when run, nothing is being saved. Can anyone tell me what I've missed...?

```
def file_saveAs():
   from tkFileDialog import asksaveasfilename
   contents = inputText.get(1.0, "end-1c")
   save_file = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = ".txt", initialdir = r"\\some\file\path\here")
   line = []
   for line in contents:
        line = line.strip()
        with open(save_file, "w") as outputFile:
           outputFile.write(line)
```

It appears to me that it's the 'for line in contents' line where the problem lies. If I change the bottom line to 'output.write(contents)', then it saves the contents correctly, but I need to filter the contents based on a couple of other factors, so need the 'for line in' part.

Many thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `for` statement to:

```
for line in contents.split("\n"):
```

You need to split the contents into a list of lines before iterating over them.

You also need to move the `with open ...` statement outside the loop:

```
with open(save_file, "w") as outputfile:
    for line in contents.split("\n"):
       outputfile.write(line+"\n")
```